# FileObserver only catches delete event

Tags: android, service, fileobserver

I have a Service which starts a FileObserver to monitor pictures which are taken by the phone camera, in particular thefile :

```
String initialPictureFolder =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).toString() + "/Camera/";
```

by this function:

```
public void startFileObserver(String filePath){
    /* It only monitors this Folder, not any Subfolder */
    myFileOsberver = new PicturesFileObserver(filePath,UploadPhotosService.this);
    myFileOsberver.startWatching();
}
```

that said, the FileObserver only catches delete events (code 512) and nothing more. Whenever I rename a file,move a file, or take a photo from the android camera, nothing happens. Am I missing anything ? Am I monitoring wrong file?

Here is the whole FileObserver class

```
private static int mask = FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS; 

public PicturesFileObserver(String path,UploadPhotosService myService) {
    super(path,mask);
    this.rootDir = path;
    this.myService = myService;
    Log.e(TAG,"Observer is initialized on: "+rootDir);

}

@Override
public void onEvent(int event, @Nullable String path) {
   event &= FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS;
   Log.e(TAG,String.valueOf(event)); // ONLY PRINTS 512 
    if (path != null) {
        if (path.endsWith(".jpg") || path.endsWith(".png")) {
            if ((event == FileObserver.CREATE)) {
                Log.e(TAG, "File was created " + path);

            } else if ((FileObserver.MODIFY & event) != 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "File was modified " + path);
            } else if ((FileObserver.DELETE & event) != 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "File was deleted " + path);
            } else if ((FileObserver.MOVED_FROM & event) != 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "File was brought here " + path);
            } else if ((FileObserver.MOVED_TO & event) != 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "File was brought here " + path);
            }
        } else
            Log.e(TAG, "Path not beeing a photo: " + path);
    }
}
```

Comment: without ```event &= FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS;```, what do you get?

Comment: What I found out is that when a photo is taken the System does not update the FileObserver instantly but after some time regardless the  event &= FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS;.  When I took a photo these are the codes I receive the following:  
 
   

32 - OPEN
1 - ACCESS
16 - CLOSE NO WRITE 
 
in random order and random  occurences of each event

Comment: I still get nothing when I rename a File inside the folder.

Comment: what is your minSdkVersion?

Comment: people have reported an Issue in the past that FileObserver doesn't work on 6+

Comment: the minSdkVersion I have on my Project right now is 14
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
So, based on your comments, should Iquit the idea of using FileObserver or should I return to older versions?Any other alternative ?